# Angular 5: httpClient is not returning JSON

Tags: angular, angular5

I got a problem with understanding how `HttpClient` works

**api.service.js**

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Task} from './task';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

interface JSONObject {
  _id: string;
  title: string;
  created_at: string;
  startTime: string;
  endTime: string;
  state: boolean;
  description: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  public tasks;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  public getAllTasks() {
    return this.http
      .get<JSONObject>(API_URL + '/api/task').subscribe(
        data => {
          this.tasks = data;
          console.log(data); //Returning Array
        });
  }
}
```

**task.component.ts**

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ApiService} from './api.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task',
  templateUrl: './task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task.component.css'],
  providers: [ApiService]
})
export class TaskComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.apiService.tasks); // <<< Not Returning JSON :(
  }

  getAllTasks() {
    return this.apiService.getAllTasks();
  }
}
```

I am new to Angular 5 and have to create a CRUD App for lesson but actually stuck in at this problem.

How can I get the JSON Object in task.component.ts ?

Comment: did the answer help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't subscribe to the observable in the service and do not store the value inside it. Change the method to:

```
public getAllTasks() {
  return this.http.get<JSONObject>(API_URL + '/api/task')
}
```

so your service is specific to handle the API requests.
Then in your component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.apiService.getAllTasks()
  .subscribe( data => {
    //now you have the data
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm. So it is best practice to not store data in services? I have much to learn in angular..

Comment: You can store them in a service, but then the best approach IMO is to use EventEmitter (https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) to "broadcast" to subscribed listeners (in components) that a value has been changed. Basically, the components subscribe to observables that emits values when the service has values changed.